# About mechanism/behavior of 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' function on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

:)

Hi guys.

Now, I'm working on Multi-hot classification by using tensorflow.

If softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits is used, the loss function increases (e.g. loss: 50 -> loss: 190000 -> loss: 2138712811 -> ...).

Therefore, I want to clarify the mechanism of softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits.

I thought that the python code of below could imitate softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits.

```
def imitation_SCEwL(logits, labels):
  _y = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
  _y = tf.clip_by_value(_y, 1e-10, 1.0)

  cross_entropy = -( labels * tf.log(_y) )
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, 1, keep_dims=True)
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean( cross_entropy )

  return cross_entropy
```

However, behavior is different between genuine (implemented in tensorflow) and the above code.

Using the above code, the loss function converges.

why? 
I'm changing only code below.

```
def loss_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels):
  _y = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(_y)

  return cross_entropy
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea of your logic is correct but you should specify "dim" when you call softmax inside your `imitation_SCEwL` function.

See following code to calculate loss:
1. numpy implementation

```
def xent(features, labels, dim=-1):
  if dim is -1:
    dim = len(features.shape) - 1
  one_only_on_dim = list(features.shape)
  one_only_on_dim[dim] = 1
  e = np.exp(features - np.reshape(
      np.amax(
        features, axis=dim), one_only_on_dim))
  probs = e / np.reshape(np.sum(e, axis=dim), one_only_on_dim)
  l = -np.sum(labels * np.log(probs + 1.0e-20), axis=dim)
  return l
```

2. tensorflow native implementation

""

```
def loss_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(np_features, np_labels, dim=-1):
    loss = nn_ops.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=np_labels, logits=np_features, dim=dim)
    tf_loss = sess.run(loss)
    return tf_loss
```

3. revised version of your function

""

```
def imitation_SCEwL(logits, labels, dim=-1):
  _y = tf.nn.softmax(logits, dim=dim)
  cross_entropy = labels * (-tf.log(_y))
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, 1, keep_dims=True)
  retval = sess.run(cross_entropy)
  return retval
```

I tested that all of loss values from these functions are equivalent.  Let me know if they don't work for you.